# Does memory card auto-eject no longer work in Lightroom Classic?

Tags: lightroom

I am using Lightroom Classic version 10.1. Recently, the feature to auto eject the memory card after import has stopped working. I cant find an option in Preferences to stop or start this function. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Lightroom with no luck. Thanks!

Comment: If you do only read-only operations with card it is safe to eject it physically w/o need of software eject.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

When you have actually inserted a card which has photos the import window pops up in Lightroom. On the left side  of the window is a list of devices. Just above the (Camera or Card Reader) Device there is a check box for "Eject after Import". This only appears when you have a card with images inserted.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

NOTE the eject option ONLY shows up for the likes of SD cards. What I noticed on my issue herein was based on a CFAST card placed in a ProGrade reader. In those cases the eject option is unavailble.

Answer (score 0):

The ‘eject after import’ checkbox is not available. [image]